# xticklabels disappear after rotation

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting several datasets on a grid.  The time series extends over a period of one year, so I would like to have a month-year tick marker, but the tick labels quickly overlap one another.  To get around this I attempted to rotate the xticklables.  However, this is not working as expected.  Here is a non-minimal working example:

```
from __future__ import division, print_function

import pandas as pd, numpy as np
from pylab import *

index = pd.date_range('20140901','20150901',freq='1H')
data  = np.sin( np.pi*np.arange(index.shape[0])/180 )
df = pd.DataFrame(index=index,data=data,columns=list("A"))

fig = figure( figsize=(3.25,4.0) )
gs  = GridSpec(5,2)
gs.update(left=0.08, right=0.925, top=0.95, bottom=0.05, hspace=0.0, wspace=0.0)

ax0 = subplot(gs[0])
ax1 = subplot(gs[1])
ax2 = subplot(gs[2])
ax3 = subplot(gs[3])
ax4 = subplot(gs[4])
ax5 = subplot(gs[5])
ax6 = subplot(gs[6])
ax7 = subplot(gs[7])

for axis in xrange(8):
    ax = eval('ax'+str(axis))

    ax.plot(df.index,df.A,'k')

    # format y-axes
    if axis in np.arange(1,8,2):
        ax.set_yticks(np.arange(-1.5,1.5,0.50),minor=False)
        ax.set_yticks(np.arange(-1.5,1.5,0.25),minor=True)
        ax.set_yticklabels([])

    elif axis in np.arange(2,8,2):
        ax.set_yticks(np.arange(-1.5,1.5,0.50),minor=False)
        ax.set_yticks(np.arange(-1.5,1.5,0.25),minor=True)

    elif axis==0:
        ax.set_yticks(np.arange(-1.5,1.6,0.50),minor=False)
        ax.set_yticks(np.arange(-1.5,1.5,0.25),minor=True)

    ax.set_ylim([-1.5,1.5])

    # format x-axes
    if axis in np.arange(0,6):
        ax.set_xticklabels([])
        ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(dates.MonthLocator(interval=1))
        ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(dates.MonthLocator(interval=3))

    elif axis in [6,7]:
        ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(dates.MonthLocator(interval=1))
        ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(dates.MonthLocator(interval=3))
        ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%b-%Y'))

    ax.set_xlim([dt.datetime(2014,9,1),dt.datetime(2015,9,1)])

    ax.tick_params(axis='both',which='major',direction='in',length=4,width=1,labelsize=8)
    ax.tick_params(axis='both',which='minor',direction='in',length=2,width=1)    


    # insert text boxes
    ax.annotate('A', 
                xycoords='axes fraction',
                xy=(0.05,0.75), 
                horizontalalignment='left',
                verticalalignment='bottom',
                fontsize=8)

ax6.set_xticklabels(ax6.get_xticklabels(),rotation=45)
ax7.set_xticklabels(ax7.get_xticklabels(),rotation=45)
```

If I run the script as is there will be no ticklabels on the lowermost x axis.  However, if I comment out the last two lines, run the script, then manually enter the last two lines the rotation is done as expected.  I have looked at several methods of rotating the tick labels, none of which work (i.e. they all have the same "disappearing" problem).  Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?

Python 2.7, Matplotlib 1.5.1, Pandas 0.18.0

[image][image]

Comment: Done.  The first figure was produced by running the script without the last two lines commented, the second was produced by commenting the last two lines, running the script, then manually entering the last two lines. You can re-create these figures by running the posted script.

Comment: By the way, I apologize for the poor image resolution, but all that needs to be seen is that the tick labels are not showing up on the first image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing your program like this will work.

```
# format x-axes
if axis in np.arange(0,6):
    ax.set_xticklabels([])
    ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(dates.MonthLocator(interval=1))
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(dates.MonthLocator(interval=3))

elif axis in [6,7]:
    ax.set_xticklabels(index.strftime('%b-%Y'),rotation=45)      # Add this line
    ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(dates.MonthLocator(interval=1))
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(dates.MonthLocator(interval=3))
    # ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%b-%Y')) # This not needed
```

Comment: Works beautifully.  Do you know why my original code caused the labels to disappear?  Perhaps just a quark in pylab...

Comment: By the way, I edited your answer to include the rotation=45 parameter in ax.set_xticklabels since label rotation was part of the question.